# iOS 7 multi spaces issue

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, nsstring, ios7

I need to animate label text with `@"text .   ", @"text  .  ", @"text   . ", @"text    ."`

So user will see only dot animation. I use a center alignment for the label text.

I use timer for that purposes:

```
- (void)processTimerFired:(NSTimer *)timer {
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [timer userInfo];
    NSMutableString *string = [[dict objectForKey:@"label"] mutableCopy];
    int dotNumber = [[dict objectForKey:@"dot"] intValue];
    if (dotNumber == 3) {
        dotNumber = 1;
    }
    else {
        dotNumber += 1;
    }

    [dict setObject:@(dotNumber) forKey:@"dot"];

    for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        if (i == dotNumber) {
            [string appendString:@"."];
        }
        else {
            [string appendString:@" "];
        }
    }

    self.informationLabel.text = string;
}
```

on iOS 6 everything is OK, but on iOS 7 it seems that xcode reduces the number of spaces, so the origin of the text always becomes different. And that's why it seems that text is shaken.

I tried to add "+" at the end for test. And everything became OK. So It seems that xcode removes 'excess' spaces only when there is not other symbol after that.

Comment: Yeah I checked it and seems like `UILabel` is trimming the text

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing test with that issue and I'm seen that you need to center the text to right. That's my code:

```
self.text = @[@"Text.  ",@"Text . ", @"Text  ."];
[self.shorLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
[self doAnimation:@0];
```

And doAnimation method:

```
- (void) doAnimation: (NSNumber *)index
{
    int indexInt = ([index intValue] +1)%3;
    [self.shorLabel setText:self.text[indexInt]];
    [self.shorLabel sizeToFit];
    [self.shorLabel setFrame:CGRectMake((self.view.frame.size.width - self.shorLabel.frame.size.width)/2, self.shorLabel.frame.origin.y, self.shorLabel.frame.size.width, self.shorLabel.frame.size.height)];
    [self performSelector:@selector(doAnimation:) withObject:@(indexInt) afterDelay:0.2];
}
```

Comment: No, I need TextAllignmentCenter

Comment: Ok, you can take another approach recalculating the position in every step.

Answer (score 0):

What if you replace the space `@" "` with a Unicode non-breakable space `@" "` (obtained by Alt-space on a Mac) ?